# How can I end passing Jest test on Circle CI?

Tags: npm, jestjs, continuous-integration, yaml, circleci

My app passes all the tests in Circle CI. However, after it passes it just hangs there until it times out at 10 minutes, and is eventually deemed failed.

Tests do pass locally. I get:

```
Test Suites: 1 failed, 11 passed, 12 total
Tests:       1 failed, 55 passed, 56 total
Snapshots:   2 obsolete, 10 passed, 10 total
Time:        11.196 s
Ran all test suites matching /a|q/i.

Active Filters: filename /a|q/
 › Press c to clear filters.

Watch Usage
 › Press a to run all tests.
 › Press f to run only failed tests.
 › Press o to only run tests related to changed files.
 › Press u to update failing snapshots.
 › Press q to quit watch mode.
 › Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 › Press t to filter by a test name regex pattern.
 › Press Enter to trigger a test run.
```

at the end in my local terminal. Then I would press Ctrl-C. I get the same thing in Circle CI:

```
Test Suites: 1 failed, 10 passed, 11 total
Tests:       1 failed, 49 passed, 50 total
Snapshots:   2 obsolete, 9 passed, 9 total
Time:        10.752 s
Ran all test suites matching /a/i.

Active Filters: filename /a/
 › Press c to clear filters.

Watch Usage
 › Press a to run all tests.
 › Press f to run only failed tests.
 › Press o to only run tests related to changed files.
 › Press u to update failing snapshots.
 › Press q to quit watch mode.
 › Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 › Press t to filter by a test name regex pattern.
 › Press Enter to trigger a test run.

Too long with no output (exceeded 10m0s): context deadline exceeded
```

except for the last line.

This is my `.circleci/config.yml`:

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  node: circleci/node@4.7.0

# Define a job to be invoked later in a workflow.
# See: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#jobs
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: 'circleci/node:latest'
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: 
          name: "npm install"
          command: sudo npm install
      - run: 
          name: "npm build"
          command: sudo npm run build
  test:
    docker:
      - image: 'circleci/node:latest'
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: 
          name: "npm install"
          command: sudo npm install
      - run: 
          name: "npm test"
          command: sudo npm test a

  workflows:
    build_and_test:
      jobs:
        - build
        - test:
            requires:
              - build
```

build works fine. All spacing/linting is correct.

These are the commands in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "begin": "react-scripts start && node server/server.js",
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install && npm run build"
  },
```

I have also tried adding

```
- run: q
```

after the test line in `.yml` file, but it won't even get to the `run q` because `sudo npm test a` does not end as mentioned above.

Comment: `sudo npm test a` - why `a`? For that matter, why `sudo`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe 'a' for running all tests. If i just run npm test, I get "No tests found related to files changed since last commit.
Press `a` to run all tests, or run Jest with `--watchAll`."

sudo, because Circle CI will say command not found (npm test) if I do not put sudo

Comment: Fundamentally you're running Jest in interactive mode, which is clearly wrong in CI. But most CI environments (including CircleCI: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#built-in-environment-variables) set `CI=true`, which Jest also recognises. This makes me think you have some configuration you're not showing.

Comment: I have shown all config for yml file and the npm commands. The solution was to include '--watchAll=false' at the end of test command. The test was hanging in CI because it was continually watching after the test. Maybe CRA tests default to watch mode. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe It does exist the test when done, but actually, it still fails the test in CI haha.. Any suggestions on where i can check for configurations? I am using Create react app.

Comment: See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests

Comment: see if it helps https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--forceexit

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 "test": "react-scripts test --watchAll=false",
```

Adding

```
--watchAll=false
```

at the end of

```
"test": "react-scripts test",
```

solved the issue.

Test in Circle CI was hanging because it was in watch mode.

Had to explicitly disable watch mode.

CRA's Jest comes with configured watch mode by default.

Also check if any snapshot is obsolete; this will prevent tests from passing in the CI.

Comment: Per https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#continuous-integration and https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#built-in-environment-variables this should not be necessary, though.

Comment: I just ran into this same situation too, having --watchAll in the jest command caused the test pipeline to hang after the tests completed.  Not sure why, but removing it fixed the issue. (already running with CI=true)